# How to override onBackPressed but also get the touch event?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, touch, back-button

I'm working on an Android project in Java and I'd like to get the **MotionEvent** when the user hits the back button (onBackPressed).
I know how to override the back button press, and i know how to get the touch event from touches in my activity, but I couldn't find a way to get the touch event details out of the back button press.
The goal is to write the user's touch event details (as if the user touches a regular view) to a file, even when the back button is pressed.
Is it possible? if so, how can I do it?